# Difference between dlopen and System.loadLibrary()

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, dlopen

In Android, is there a difference between a library loaded using `System.loadLibrary()` in Java and a library loaded using `dlopen()` in *native* code? Can I just call a function in the dynamically loaded library directly the standard way through `JNI`, or do I have to retrieve the functions using `dlsym()` and create a bunch of *stubs*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`System.loadLibrary()` loads a library in the Dalvik VM, `dlopen()` simply loads the library in you native process. If you want to access your library from Java, you need to write some glue JNI code. How you implement those is not important: you can link directly, or use `dlopen()`, etc.

Comment: Is there any performance difference between these two